# Update Field using a set of IDs from another table at random

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 Tables. `model`, `category`, and `document`. Documents belong in a category, which belongs to a model, and models can have multiple categories, which can have multiple documents.

I'm trying to build & execute this query in PHP, assigning each document a randomly selected category from a list of the categories in the currently selected model. 
So, if a model has 10 categories (cat1-cat10), with each of those categories having 10 documents, the end result would make 1000 documents have a random_category_id field of cat1 - cat10 assigned at random, but not overwriting the existing category_id of the document.

Later in the application, I need to be able to calculate when document.category_id == document.random_category_id.

Is there a way to do this in one query. I'm new to SQL & PHP (and haven't mastered any kind of JOIN yet), so please forgive the blunders in database design & mixed coding approaches. I know the below example will not execute.

I'm using MySQL 5.5.28 with InnoDB.

**Pseudocode Example**

```
$catList = SELECT category_id FROM category WHERE model_id = '$current_model_id'
UPDATE document.random_category_id = RANDOM($catList) WHERE document.model_id = '$current_model_id'
```

Thank you!

Comment: There may be a way to do this in one query but the solution is going to be highly dependent on the database you are using.